# How to disable address bar link after login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router

I am trying to create authentication system with react everything is working. I have one private route if there is no user then it redirects to login page.

This is my private route

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuth } from '../../context/AuthContext'

export default function PrivateRoute({children}) {
    const { currentUser } = useAuth()
    
    if(!currentUser){
        return <Navigate to= '/login' />
    }

    return children;
}
```

Problem is after login I get redirect to update-profile page but if I enter login link in address bar it logs out and takes user back to login page. I don't know how to deal with that.

This is my context

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase-config'

const AuthContext = React.createContext()

export function useAuth(){
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {

    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    function singup(email, password){
        return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)   
    }

    function login(email, password){
        return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }
    function logout(){
        return auth.signOut()
    }

    function resetPassword(email){
        return auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
    }

    function updateEmail(email){
        return currentUser.updateEmail(email)
    }

    function updatePassword(password){
        return currentUser.updatePassword(password)
    }

    useEffect(() =>{
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user =>{
            setCurrentUser(user)
            setLoading(false)
        })

        return unsubscribe
    }, [])

    const value = {
        currentUser,
        login,
        singup,
        logout,
        resetPassword,
        updateEmail,
        updatePassword
    }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
        { !loading && children }
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you sow the code for `useAuth`?

Comment: It's unclear what you are saying is the issue and what you are asking for. It *sounds* like you are saying you are manually entering a URL in the address bar. When you do this it will reload the page, which reloads your app. Anything stored in state is wiped. If you are asking how to keep the state then you'll need to persist it to longer-term storage, i.e. localStorage. If this is the case then please include all relevant code that handles the auth state that you are asking to retain in the app.

Comment: sorry for not describing clearly i am using context which i added above, yes i am manually entering URL i want to store it to localStorage but i don't know how

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

Since you are manually entering a URL in the address bar, when you do this it will reload the page, which reloads your app. Anything stored in state is wiped. To keep the state you'll need to persist it to longer-term storage, i.e. localStorage.

## Solution

Using localStorage you can initialize the `currentUser` *from* localStorage, and use a `useEffect` hook to persist the `currentUser` *to* localStorage.

Example:

```
export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"))
  );
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(currentUser));
  }, [currentUser]);

  ...

  useEffect(() =>{
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    login,
    singup,
    logout,
    resetPassword,
    updateEmail,
    updatePassword
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help i tried lot of solution but nothing worked.....

Comment: @smitagravat Can you clarify exactly what you tried and exactly what isn't working?

Comment: I tried youtube video solutions concept was same to store data in local storage but code was buggy, but now i ran into different problem if u can help, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72641190/react-gallary-app-uploads-image-two-times)

Answer (score 0):

When you re-enter a link in the address bar it deletes all your saved context, if you want a simple way to save the login state, you can save the currentUser object in the localStorage(this is a very basic way, not recommended in real websites), and then when the page loads you can use useEffect to get that data from the localStorage and set currentUser to the user you save in the localStorage.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).